# Unhealthy cloud service in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a red exclamation mark beside the status of my Azure Cloud Service. How can I get to the problem?

**Here is what I get in the portal:**
[image: My Cloud Service Page]

**Here is what I get in the Dashboard**
[image: My Dashboard Page]

**Update**

This problem happen after updating MVC packages from version 4 to version 5.

Comment: Not programming related. Ask on http://serverfault.com instead.

Comment: @spender I will update my question

Comment: @m.samy did you figure this out? I am also having this problem after upgrading from MVC4 to MVC5.

Comment: @user1308743 just downgrade from MVC5 to MVC4

Comment: Did you figure this out.  I am having the same problem with a MVC 5.1 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either remote desktop to the cloud instance and review the Windows Event Logs for exceptions or redeploy with IntelliTrace Enabled. If you choose the later, you can download the IntelliTrace logs from Visual Studio and debug
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you switch to the Instances tab from the dashboard?  You should see a message indicating some type of exception.

Also, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx and go through the troubleshooting scenarios.  They will walk through exactly how to troubleshoot this type of issue.